# TRIGGER to divide polygons

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have two tables: PLOT and ROAD.
Each time i add a new segment on ROAD I want to divide my polygons from PLOT intersected by ROAD.

It works without the trigger. But if i had the trigger as below oracle ask me to enter a value in ":new.GID" in the window 'Bind Parameter'.

I am sure i didn't write the trigger properly, could you help me please?
Thanxs a lot

```
DROP TRIGGER "PLOT";
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "PLOT"
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON "ROAD"
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

-- I insert in NEW_ROWS the result from the SDO_DIFFERENCE    
INSERT INTO "NEW_ROWS" ("GID","GEOM") AS
WITH TOTAL_PLOT AS (
SELECT c."GID", c."GEOM"
FROM "ROAD" T
JOIN "PLOT" c ON SDO_RELATE(c."GEOM", T."GEOM", 'mask=ANYINTERACT') = 'TRUE'
WHERE T."GID" = :new."GID"
)

SELECT a."GID", SDO_GEOM.SDO_DIFFERENCE(a."GEOM", d."GEOM", 0.05) As "GEOM" FROM "TOTAL_PLOT" a, "ROAD" d
WHERE d."GID" = :new."GID";

INSERT INTO "USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA" (TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DIMINFO)
VALUES ('NEW_ROWS','GEOM',
        MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ARRAY(
          MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('X',140955.0,445546.0,0.001),
          MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Y',34998.0,291800.0,0.001))
END;
/
```

Comment: If you're running this in SQL Developer, are you running the create on its own as a statement (control-enter), or as a script (F5)? (It also won't like the `AS` on the first insert, and you're missing `);` on the second one. No idea if the rest of what you're doing makes sense... Having a trigger with the same name as a table looks confusing though.)

Comment: I've try them both. Running the create as a script gives me no error but on its own i have a message error. Does it mean that's the trigger work?

Comment: When run as a script does it say it compiled cleanly or with errors? You can do 'show errors', or check the compiler log window.

Comment: i've added just 'show errors' at the end of the script is that right? (Btw i am using DBeaver, i don't know if it change anything?) It returns no errors from what i can see

Comment: Yes, that's odd; I get `Trigger PLOT compiled` then `Errors: check compiler log` but show errors gets `No errors`. The compiler log window does show errors though. Or you can `select * from user_errors where type = 'TRIGGER' and name = 'PLOT;'`. I've mentioned two errors in an earlier comment.

Comment: Ok thanxs for the answer, I will try to correct it